# C++ Input space separated integers and store inside an int array

Tags: c++

I am trying to input int array size and then get N space-separated integers as shown below:

```
int main()
{

    int N;
    cin>>N;
    int *arr = new int(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
 
    if (isSpiralSorted(arr, N))
        cout << "yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but the input:

```
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

actually takes:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Can someone help me here in understanding what am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI misspelling `seperate` instead of `separate` is the most common orthography error in the English language.

Comment: se**par**ate into **par**ts. The etymology is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a single scalar with `new int(N)` and not an array. If you change it to `new int[N]` then it runs fine.

Also you forgot to delete the array in the end.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int *arr = new int[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        std::cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/caza1336s

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! This was extremely helpful. Btw once thr main returns does the variables not get destroyed automatically?

Comment: @ShivamSahil No, this is not Java my friend. You always need to deallocate. That is why idioms like RAII exist. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii

Comment: BTW instead of using new/delete, I'd just use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: I got it haha ok, so you mean that `std::vector<int>` would auto deallocate?
 btw am a TypeScript developer. I hate Java,I like Scala which seems to be kind of less verbose. but unfortunately,  there's no cure 

Comment: Yes, std::vector will allocate/deallocate the internal pointer for you.